# Draw hemisphere in SceneKit using Swift

Tags: swift4, scenekit

How to draw a hemisphere in scene kit programatically using swift, I trying the build the hemisphere robot head using scene kit but did not how to do, I came to know we can use SCNShape with bezier path

```
let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0.4, height: 0.4))
let bottomNode = SCNNode()
let hemisphere = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
```

but did not generated the hemisphere. Can any one help me on this?